# Count blocks in a 2D grid

Tags: code-golf, grid, combinatorics, counting

## Challenge description

Let's define an `W` x `H` **grid** as a two-dimensional array of length `H` whose each subarray is of length `W`. Example: a 2x3 grid (`.` character used as a blank):

```
..
..
..
```

A **unit** is a single point of a grid. A **block** is either a single unit or a set of contiguous units (meaning each unit of a block has at least another one next to, above or below it). In the 10x10 grid below there are 4 blocks (units represented by `X`'s):

```
........X.   ........1.
..X.......   ..2.......
..X.......   ..2.......
..X.......   ..2.......
.......X..   .......3..
.......XX.   .......33.
.......XX.   .......33.
..X.......   ..4.......
..XX..X...   ..44..4...
...XXXX...   ...4444...
```

Two blocks are **distinct** if either their positions in the grid or the number of blocks they consist of are different. In the 10x10 grid below there are 5 blocks (they're all 2x2 squares, but their positions are different, therefore they're distinct):

```
..........   ..........
.XX....XX.   .11....22.
.XX....XX.   .11....22.
..........   ..........
.......XX.   .......33.
.......XX.   .......33.
....XX....   ....44....
....XX....   ....44....
XX........   55........
XX........   55........
```

Given two integers `W` and `H` `(W, H > 0)`, calculate the number of distinct blocks that can be constructed within a `W` x `H` grid.

## Sample inputs / outputs

```
(1, 1) -> 1     | only a 1x1 block can be constructed
(1, 2) -> 3     | two 1x1 blocks, and one 1x2 block
(2, 2) -> 13
(3, 3) -> 218
(4, 4) -> 11506
```

## Notes

- Remember that this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so make your code as short as possible!
- Relevant sequences: [A059525](https://oeis.org/A059525), [A059020](https://oeis.org/A059020)

Comment: To clarify: are we supposed to compute the total number of 4-way connected non-empty subsets of the W x H grid?

Comment: Yes, I just realized that this whole challenge could be worded much more concisely, but that's the gist.

Comment: @shooqie The gist of what?

Comment: Of @Zgarb just said, it's an expression...

Comment: @TimmyD: it was supposed to be a strict inequality, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: `Two blocks are distinct if both their positions in the grid and the number of blocks they consist of are different.` I think you mean an `either`/`or` rather than a `both`/`and` here. Else, the sentence doesn't match the example with the 5 2x2 blocks. Also, it would probably be a good thing if you explicitly stated that the blocks for counting aren't all placed on the grid at the same time. That's implied by your `(1,2)` example, but not explicit. With that being the case, this is *very* similar to the recent count-the-rectangle challenges.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>208</s> <s>184</s> <s>169</s> <s>167</s> 163 bytes

```
w,h=input()
def f(x):global g;o=g;g&=~2**x;o>g>[x/w==(x+s)/w<f(x+s)or-1<x/w+s<h<f(x+s*w)for s in[-1,1]]
n=i=1<<w*h
while i:g=i=i-1;f(len(bin(g))-3);n-=g>0
print~-n
```